# Are the double quotes around the string 'sport' HTML value of the value attribute unnecessary as 'sport' is already a string with double quotes?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Those were the code snippets from CS50 2022 - Lecture 9 - Flask.

```
<select name="sport">
    <option disabled selected>Sport</option>
    {% for sport in sports %}
        <option value="{{ sport }}">{{ sport }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Are the double quotes around the string 'sport' unnecessary as 'sport' is already a string with double quotes? I personally want to write something like this, a little bit differently, without the quotes around `{{ sport }}`

```
<select name="sport">
    <option disabled selected>Sport</option>
    {% for sport in sports %}
        <option value={{ sport }}>{{ sport }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: I doubt that the value of `sport` really contains double quotes. Double quotes are used in source code to create string literals, but they're not actually part of the value.

Comment: Use `View Source` to see the result of the substitution. Do you see `value="'football'"` or `value="football"`?

Comment: Try passing in a value of `sport` containing spaces and see what happens.

Comment: literally `value="football"`!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the quotes are unnecessary, you can write this code like this:

```
<select name="sport">
    <option disabled selected>Sport</option>
    {% for sport in sports %}
        <option value={{ sport }}>{{ sport }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Please provide support for your answer (documentation, another stackoverflow answer, personal experimentation with input/outputs, etc)